# Apple generates wrong qr code for passbook

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, zxing, passbook

I have an ipad application with ZXingWidget for decoding qr codes which generates in another iphone app. When I generates qr code via chart.googleapis.com or ZXing tool everything is ok. But when I create pass with barcode (for passbook) apple generates totally different qr code and ZXingWidget not decoding it correctly. Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: If you think you have found a reproducible bug, then please log it with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Can you provide an example to reproduce what you are experiencing?

Comment: I have issues with special STX UTX and SUB characters when using passkit to generate a passbook as well

Answer (score 1):

The first thing too look at is encoding of barcode.

As Apple's documentation suggests:

> Barcode scanners and software typically use the ISO 8859-1 encoding, also known as Latin-1. Unicode in particular is poorly supported by most systems. Passbook itself supports all encodings supported by Foundation.

Sample passes by default have

```
"messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"
```

As I can see from ZXing tool, the default encoding is UTF-8, so to get the same encoding result from Passbook, use

```
"messageEncoding" : "utf-8"
```

Also, examine decoding supported by ZXingWidget, to choose the most appropriate one for QR displayed on your passes.